# Disabling desktop icons in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, icons, configuration, gnome-shell

I don't much like the look of desktop icons, so I decided I wanted to disable them. I googled the issue, and everything that came up told me to hit <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>f2</kbd>, type `gconf-editor` and hit enter to open the config. From there I could find the option to disable them. Well, Ubuntu told me this wasn't a valid command. Someone else suggested to try entering it into the terminal, I did and it didn't work but informed me I could enter

```
sudo apt install gconf-editor
```

to get it working.

I did, and after this when  I tried to enter gconf-editor in the <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>f2</kbd> menu, it did work. However, the configuration editor for me is very bare bones and does not contain much, including the option to disable dekstop icons spelled out in the other post:

[image: This is what it looks like.]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

GConf is obsolete and it has been replaced by `dconf`/`gsettings`. To disable desktop icons run the following command in Terminal.

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background show-desktop-icons false
```

For a GUI alternative use `dconf-editor` instead of `gconf-editor`, navigate to `/org/gnome/desktop/background/`, and disable `show-desktop-icons` option.

Alternatively, use GNOME Tweaks (`gnome-tweaks`) to turn off the "**Show Icons**" option in the *Desktop* tab.

[image]

Comment: The terminal command and dconf-editor solutions are failing quietly for me in Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS.

Comment: This question and answer are specifically for Ubuntu 18.04 and not at all applicable to 20.04 as desktop icons [are handled completely differently](https://askubuntu.com/q/1231413/480481) in newer Ubuntu releases.