# Desktop icons have disappeared in 18.04

Tags: 18.04, nautilus, nemo

As I usually just switch between windows that are already open, I don't see my desktop often so I'm not sure when this happened, but at some point somewhat recently everything on the desktop disappeared. I still have a desktop folder with all the files accounted for, but that's it. If I try to drag/drop anything to the desktop, it doesn't work. Things are visible if I switch to another DE.

I'm still a Linux newbie, though I managed to figure out how to switch to Nemo around the same time. Don't remember which I did first, but there was some time between switching file managers and the desktop breaking. How do I diagnose/repair this?

Comment: Possibly related to https://askubuntu.com/questions/1089610/disabling-desktop-icons-in-ubuntu-18-04

Comment: That did the trick. Thank you!