# Can't delete icons in my desktop

Tags: icons, directory, shortcuts

I recently got the ubuntu installed and my desktop was totally clear. There was no icon or folder. 
My desktop folder in the "/home/myPC/" was the name "Área de trabalho" but I wanted to change it for "Desktop". When I did this all folders in "home/myPC/" moved to "shortcuts" in my desktop.
I wanted my desktop to be clear, so I moved all the "shortcuts" to the Thrash.
I thought it would solve my problem but when I saw my /home/myPC again all the folders that were there got deleted too. So these "Shortcuts" was actually the real "folders"?
I'm confused, can someone help me?

Actually my topic is confusing, but I tried my best to describe my problem.

Comment: I know this isn't the answer to your question but if you simply want to remove the icons on your desktop screen, you can follow [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1089615/167115).

Answer (score 1):

You might want to adapt some files in `$HOME/.config`:

- user-dirs.dirs
- user-dirs.locale

I feel with you; it annoys me to no end that today's desktops insist on creating a dozen useless directories with really weird names. But you can tweak it to what *you* want if you edit those files. I use:

user-dirs.locale:

```
en_US
```

user-dirs.dirs:

```
XDG_DESKTOP_DIR="$HOME/Desktop"
XDG_DOWNLOAD_DIR="$HOME/tmp"
XDG_TEMPLATES_DIR="$HOME/doc/templates"
XDG_PUBLICSHARE_DIR="$HOME/"
XDG_DOCUMENTS_DIR="$HOME/doc"
XDG_MUSIC_DIR="/work/music/"
XDG_PICTURES_DIR="/work/photos"
XDG_VIDEOS_DIR="/work/video"
```