# How Do You Disable Desktop Icons That Were Placed By 21.04?

Tags: desktop-icons, 21.04

After updating to 21.04, I, all of a sudden, have a home folder, internal drive icons, and a recycling bin icon on my desktop, which were not there before. I tried following [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/1089615/1168729) answer but it did not work.
The command that it gave

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background show-desktop-icons false
```

ran with no output, and had no effect.

And the example that it showed with gnome tweaks wont work for me, as I do not have a "Desktop" section in gnome tweaks. I have the "dconf editor", and I navigated to where it mentioned: `/org/gnome/desktop/background/` to disable `show-desktop-icons`, but strangely enough, It is already disabled... I tried re enabling it, and then disabling it to maybe refresh the setting, but it had no effect and the desktop icons were still there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Right click on desktop. A context menu will appear.  At the bottom of the context menu click on settings. A settings popup will appear. The top half is for enabling/disabling. positioning, and sizing the desktop icons.

Comment: There is an icon on my desktop called `chrome-agimnkijcaahngcdmfeangaknmldooml-Profile_1.desktop`. That icon does not become hidden no matter what I do. How can I hide that?